# ATtiny85 communication with computer through USB

Tags: attiny

I am trying to receive and send some data from a computer to an ATtiny through USB. Can an ATtiny85 IC communicate with a computer through USB? If yes, how should it be connected?

Comment: The answers don't seem to address the core question. I believe he is asking how to communicate with a computer over the USB port AFTER burning the code. The answers talk about connecting seemingly for the purpose of programming and developing and loading any program. The question is, how do you communicate with a host PC over USB FROM the attiny with your own code? I have the same question. Paul

Answer (score 8):

Digispark made a lot of these as part of a "cheap Arduino USB interface" project a while back.

This is my Digispark, it's pretty cute:

[image: Digispark]

They have a [web page here](https://digistump.com/wiki/digispark).

---

I got them for about $2 each. The board has the ATtiny85, a voltage regulator, and a handful of other parts.

Schematic (courtesy of [Digistump Wiki](https://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/tutorials/digispark)):

[image: Digispark schematic]

---

More information about the Virtual USB idea at [USB-Keyboard with Arduino and V-USB library, an example](http://blog.petrockblock.com/2012/05/19/usb-keyboard-with-arduino-and-v-usb-library-an-example/).

Comment: If someone is wondering if you can use SPI devices with it due to the low amount of pins, the answer is yes, you can.

Answer (score 5):

> Can an ATtiny85 ic communicate with a computer through USB?if yes,how should be the connection?

Have you checked the web? There are many such projects. Here is a link to one:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Digispark-DIY-The-smallest-USB-Arduino/

Please remember "Google is your friend".

Cheers!

Comment: Nooo... not Google... [Marjory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fraggle_Rock_characters#Marjory_the_Trash_Heap)!!!

Comment: Whatever make you happy - "Google == Web search tool of your liking" :)

Comment: The Digispark (of which I bought a few) works quite well. It is based on the "Virtual USB" (V-USB) concept which you can find with a \*ahem\* search-engine-of-your-choice search.

Comment: @MikaelPatel Could you please highlight the most important parts of the content you linked? It's currently very much link-only answer.

Comment: @Avamander Please see the schematics provided below by Nick. That should answer all your questions about how to connect the ATtiny85 to USB.